# Resolve Error when importing Gradle project into IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

When I try to import a Gradle project into IntelliJ, I get:

```
Resolve Error

No such property: spredfastRepoUsername for class:
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

This is strange, because I do have `spredfastRepoUsername` defined in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`, as evidenced by a successful `./gradlew clean test` in  bash.

Any idea why this might happen? My coworkers can import the project into their IntelliJ without issue.

Clicking on `Show Log` does nothing.

System:

- https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/intellij-settings.jar
- IntelliJ 14.1.5, enterprise license
- gradlew 2.4
- JDK 1.8
- Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be bad settings. If you regularly export/import settings between different computers, IntelliJ can get confused about file paths, that should be relative to any user's home directory, but are actually absolute.

After resetting my IntelliJ settings, I was able to import the Gradle project.

If you want to safely backup/restore/sync your settings, it's best to do that with a plugin that respects home-relative file paths, such as https://github.com/develar/settings-repository

**Update**

The problem also turned about to be:

Ensure that IntelliJ's Gradle settings are configured to use `<your home directory/.gradle` as the Service Directory, not the gradle bin home. :P